# get first template parameter of a class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `foo` which takes two template parameters, what I want to do is defaulting the second parameter to the first template parameter of the first parameter if it exists. `foo` would look like

```
template<typename Class, typename T = typename first_template_parameter<Class>::type>
class foo
{
   ...
}
```

and if `Class` has been defined as `template<typename A, typename B, ...> class bar` I want `T` to be `A`. So for example `foo<std::map<int, float>>` would have `Class = std::map<int, float>` and `T = int`, `foo<int, char>` would have `Class = int` and `T = char`. How can I implement `first_template_parameter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drilling down into the first template parameter requires a little bit of work involving specialization:

```
template<typename T> struct first_template_type;

template<template<typename T, typename ...> class t,
     typename T, typename ...Args>
struct first_template_type<t<T, Args...>> {
    typedef T type_t;
};

template<typename T>
using first_template_type_t=typename first_template_type<T>::type_t;
```

Once that's out of the way, the rest is pretty boring:

```
#include <map>

template<typename Class,
     typename T = first_template_type_t<Class>>
class foo
{
public:
    T bar;
};

foo<std::map<int, char>> Foo;

int *baz=&Foo.bar;
```